# My class not shown in xaml  so that can be added as resource in SilverLight

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I have created a class so that I can bind it to a combo box. I have a solution where there are two projects test and test.web. In the test.web I have added a new class so that I can bind it to a combobox. In the same test.web I have created few entities with help of ADO.net Entity Object Generator and those classes can be seen when I am trying to add my class as resource to a grid. Why not my class?

When I add my class as resource I get error the type '..' was not found. Verify that you are not missing assembly reference....

Comment: Are you using RIA services in your project? Otherwise you can't share website classes (which are .Net compatible) with a Silverlight client project (which uses a Silverlight version of .Net).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer. My understanding of SilverLight was wrong as I am still learning it. I found out that I cannot directly access all the class in the model on the client side directly. They all should be exposed using DomainService and DomainService is the thing which you can access on the client side, if you have to access your class expose that through DomainService.